# input throwing error when running python program

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am very new to python and trying to run a basic program. I am asking for input (name) from user. And when user enters the name, the program is throwing and error. Here is my program

```
class Student:

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def get_data(self):
        self.name = input("please enter name")
        self.age = input("now age")

    def print_data(self):
        print self.name
        print self.age


ajeet = Student("", "")

ajeet.get_data()

ajeet.print_data()
```

And below is the error

```
please enter name Apurv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/apurvgandhwani/PycharmProjects/bio/AgeClass.py", line 18, in <module>
    ajeet.get_data()
  File "/Users/apurvgandhwani/PycharmProjects/bio/AgeClass.py", line 8, in get_data
    self.name = input("please enter name")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Apurv' is not defined
```

Python version my system is using is 2.7.15

I have tried to look into the issue and from what I have read it is the python version issue. I aam supposed to use 3.x version. I installed python3 in my mac. But system is still using the old version. How am I supposed to run the program or change the python version to 3.x.

To change the python version, I have tried adding alias to the bash_profile as

```
alias python = 'python3'
```

But still there is the same error coming when I run the my program. How can I solve this?

Comment: How are you trying to run your program?

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you're not loading the `.bash_profile`. Try this

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Also to avert this error in python2 change your `input` to `raw_input` which accepts strings.

Answer (score 0):

The print lines should be enclosed in a pair of parentheses after `print` in Python 3 like this: `print()`. Otherwise you will get an error message that says: `Missing parentheses in call to 'print'`

Also when you enter a name in `def get_data(self)` the name is a string so you should either use the `str()` function in `self.name = str(input("Please enter name: "))` to turn the input name into a string or else enclose the input name in a pair of quotes to make the input name a string that way. That is how to fix the error message: `NameError: name 'Apurv' is not defined` when you try to enter `Apurv` after where it says `please enter name`.

```py
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def get_data(self):
        self.name = str(input("Please enter name: "))
        self.age = input("Please enter age: ")

    def print_data(self):
        print(self.name)
        print(self.age)  

ajeet = Student("", "")
ajeet.get_data()
ajeet.print_data()
```